# Why does Rails give me a 'No Method Error' for an attribute that exists on my model? - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is the error I get:

```
NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create

undefined method `trial_duration' for nil:NilClass
app/models/user.rb:120:in `set_trial_end'
```

This is the relevant parts of my `User.rb`

```
before_create :set_trial_end

def set_trial_end
  plan = self.plan
  end_of_trial = Date.today + self.plan.trial_duration.days
  self.trial_end_date = end_of_trial.to_date
end
```

What's strange is that if I look in my DB, for a user that is assigned a plan and look at the `trial_duration` attribute, I get a reply:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > tu
 => #<User id: 29, email: "test50@abc.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$TKKQmBYem.vDq.mwDutv2u92Vick0X0jAIUQT6A9.FM....", password_salt: "$2a$10$TKKQmBYem.vDq.mwDutv2u", reset_password_token: nil, remember_token: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 1, current_sign_in_at: "2011-06-18 23:03:12", last_sign_in_at: "2011-06-18 23:03:12", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", username: "test50", first_name: "Test", last_name: "Fifty", created_at: "2011-06-18 23:02:48", updated_at: "2011-06-18 23:03:12", invitation_token: nil, invitation_sent_at: nil, plan_id: 2, current_state: nil, confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2011-06-18 23:03:12", confirmation_sent_at: "2011-06-18 23:02:47", space_used: 0, failed_attempts: 0, unlock_token: nil, locked_at: nil, trial_end_date: "2011-07-02", active_subscription: nil, customer_id: nil> 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > tu.plan
 => #<Plan id: 2, name: "Boutique", storage: 100.0, num_of_projects: 99999, num_of_clients: 10, cached_slug: "boutique", created_at: "2011-01-31 09:46:57", updated_at: "2011-08-11 08:22:48", amount: 19, trial_duration: 14, trial_duration_unit: "days", currency: "USD", billing_cycle: 28, billing_cycle_unit: "days"> 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > tu.plan.trial_duration
 => 14
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > tu.plan.trial_duration.days
 => 14 days
```

So not sure why Rails is giving me that error.

Any ideas?

Edit 1:

In my view, I have this:

```
<% if params[:promo] %>
    <%= text_field_tag "xcode", nil, :placeholder => "Coupon Code" %><br /> 
<%= hidden_field_tag(:plan_id, "1") %>
<% end %>
```

And in the POST, from my log, you can see the parameter `plan_id` set to `1`

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-08-24 03:11:07 -0500
  Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Jp2GHxnuVOVnI/sfr1CB4EQ9URCTJynv/2Ek4AiU8Lg=", "user"=>{"username"=>"test.user", "first_name"=>"Testing", "last_name"=>"User", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"testuser@abc.com"}, "xcode"=>"testcouponcode", "plan_id"=>"1", "commit"=>"Register"}
nil
```

But I am still getting the error `Plan can't be blank` on the next page.

I have added the `after_validation` callback instead of `after_create`, so I no longer the `NoMethodError`. But the problem isn't solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using a `before_create` hook that's assuming that `self.plan` is set:

```
before_create :set_trial_end

def set_trial_end
  #...
  end_of_trial = Date.today + self.plan.trial_duration.days
```

And your error says:

```
undefined method `trial_duration' for nil:NilClass
```

So `self.plan` is `nil` during your `set_trial_end` call.

Perhaps you want an `after_create` hook so that you'll have some instance data to work with. Even then you'd want to check for `self.plan.nil?` (just in case) and use a validation to make sure you get one:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :plan_id
  #...
```

Or maybe an [`after_validation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) hook would serve you better.

Comment: How would I use the `self.plan.nil?` ? Because if I add in the validation - which makes total sense - doesn't that take care of ensuring the plan has been selected. I am trying to figure out what I would do if `self.plan.nil?` returns true...in that method. Would I just do nothing?

Comment: @marcamillion: The problem is the [order the steps happen in](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html), the `before_create` and `after_create` hooks are called before the validations. You might want to wait until `after_validation`. You'd check `if self.plan.nil?` before trying to use `self.plan`.

Comment: Also, in this particular case, what's happening is that the user is going to a specific page `register?plan_id=1&promo=awesomecoupon` that has the plan_id hardwired into the URL. When that happens, I remove the `f.collection_select` from the view that allows them to choose the plan - the idea being that the plan_id is in the params in the URL. But, once I changed to the `after_create` it won't save it because it is saying that plan can't be left blank. So I guess my question is, how do I set the plan_id based on the params in the URL in this particular method that's in my model?

Comment: So you're accidentally overwriting `plan_id` through mass assignment? You could use a hidden input instead of a `<select>` if you already know the `plan_id`, include the select if you don't know the `plan_id` and include the `<input type="hidden">` if you do.

Comment: Hey @mu-is-too-short, I updated the question with the results of your suggestions. Would love some more feedback.

Comment: I just realized something...for the `f.collection_select` that works, it produces this: `<select id="user_plan_id" name="user[plan_id]">`, but when I did the `hidden_field_tag(:plan_id, "1")` it produced this: `<input id="plan_id" name="plan_id" type="hidden" value="1" /> ` See the difference in the name. Not quite sure how to get `user[:plan_id]` for the name attribute using Rails form helpers. How do I do that?

Comment: I think `f.hidden_field` would give you the right `name` attribute, you should be able to use `hidden_field_tag 'user[plan_id]'` too.